# How to install native2ascii on Ubuntu Xenial

Tags: software-installation, 16.04

How to install `native2ascii` on Ubuntu Xenial?

I need this command for some third party scripts.

Comment: When in doubt, search package contents or use apt-file: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=%2Fbin%2Fnative2ascii&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any

Answer (score 1):

`native2ascii` is part of several packages:

```
andrew@athens:~$ native2ascii
The program 'native2ascii' can be found in the following packages:
 * gcj-4.9-jdk
 * openjdk-8-jdk-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jdk
 * gcj-5-jdk
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

And on my own Xenial system I used:

```
andrew@athens:~$ sudo apt-get install gcj-5-jdk
```

And on Xenial this installs:

```
andrew@athens:~$ native2ascii -version | head -n 1
native2ascii (GNU Classpath) 0.99
```

Searching for this particular application name in Ubuntu is made a little difficult as Xenial actually uses `gnative2ascii-5` with some `update-alternatives` manipulation:

```
andrew@athens:~$ update-alternatives --display native2ascii
native2ascii - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/gnative2ascii-5
  link currently points to /usr/bin/gnative2ascii-5
  link native2ascii is /usr/bin/native2ascii
  slave native2ascii.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/native2ascii.1.gz
/usr/bin/gnative2ascii-5 - priority 1050
  slave native2ascii.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/gnative2ascii-5.1.gz
andrew@athens:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing [@andrew.46 answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/768846/250300):

If you have a JDK and don't want to use `alternatives`, you can just create a symbolic link if `JAVA_HOME` is not already in your `PATH`:

```
sudo ln -s "$JAVA_HOME/bin/native2ascii" /usr/bin
```

I noticed it's not included in my JDK 10 installation, though.